# Symfony Unset Attribute

Tags: session, symfony

I have the following session data from symfony2

```
[attributes:protected] => Array
        (
            [_security_secured_area] => 
            [ids] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1426
                    [1] => 1427
                    [2] => 1428
                )

        )
```

I want to remove the ids 1428. I have read about $session->remove but want to,  how to use it for multi-d array ...

Comment: how do you retrieve the array with the ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session class is just a store for the data. So you have to handle this on your own:

```
$ids = $session->get('ids');
$ids = someFunctionToUnsetTheId($ids, $idToRemove);
$session->set('ids', $ids);
```

If you have some more information about the IDs, you could look into namespacing the session keys:

```
$tokens = $session->get('tokens');
$tokens['c'] = $value;
$session->set('tokens', $tokens);

$session->set('tokens/c', $value);
```

Code example taken from the Symfony [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html).